# POST Request Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit2

I've been trying to make a POST request by using Retrofit 2.0, but I have some issues. I'd be glad for any help.
I have this interface:

```
public interface HZApi {
@POST("URL")
Call<RespBody> register(@Body ReqBody request);
}
```

This are my request and response classes:

```
public class ReqBody {

@SerializedName("login")
String login;
@SerializedName("password")
String password;

public ReqBody(String login, String password){
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
  }

}

public class RespBody {

@SerializedName("login")
String login;
@SerializedName("password")
String password;
@SerializedName("isreg")
int isreg;

}
```

And part of my activity code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl("http://URL/")
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();
        HZApi api = retrofit.create(HZApi.class);

        ReqBody req = new ReqBody(login,password);
        Call<RespBody> call = api.register(req);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<RespBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RespBody> call, Response<RespBody> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //answer.setText(response.body().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RespBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("MyTag",call.toString(),t);
                }
            });
```

And when I try to make a request, JSON throws:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

I tried to make a request without special class, just by using one String argument, but it also doesn't work. Thank for all your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you send request to server is correct. 
Are you sure that server returns JSON object with simple values? Looks like it returns JSON Array, and for this reason you get this error `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`. If server returns JSON Array you will need to change your `RespBody` class accordingly.

Comment: Ruslan is correct you need to check what JSON your server is returning and make RespBody according to that

Comment: @RustemMuzafarov try to enable logging and check that is actually being sent to server. To enable logging read this simple [instruction](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses). If data is actually being sent to server it will mean that problem on server side. Your request declaration looks ok for me.

Comment: Ruslan thanks for your help. I've found a solution - I just needed to use @FormUrlEncoded annotation on my request.